# cout exe file contents from char

Tags: c++, string, char, fstream

I saved all the contents from an exe file to `char buffer`.

When I tried:

```
string bufferStr=(string)buffer;
cout<<bufferStr.length();
```

I got that `bufferStr` is much smaller than `buffer`, so I thought since i was reading an exe file that somewhere in there I had read an escape character "\0" or something.

How can I use `buffer` to `cout` or even write to a file, without buffer escaping any characters?
Thanks

Comment: C does not have `cout`, so why the C tag?

Answer (score 2):

stirng constructor doesn't know anything about length of your data and assumes that it is 0-terminated string. You should use

```
string bufferStr=string(buffer, bufferSize);
cout<<bufferStr.length();
```

with such constructor string will save also `\0` bytes.

Comment: Better yet, use std::vector<char>.

Comment: What if i wanted to read contents from `bufferStr` to a `char` without the 0-terminated cutting the data?

Comment: First of all, you can not read `stirng` to `char`, becouse char is only 1 symbol. You probably mean `char *buffer`. Use `bufferStr.c_str()` to access string's internal buffer, and `bufferStr.length()` to get it's size. To copy data to your own buffer use `memcpy(buffer, bufferStr.c_str() , bufferStr.length())`.